# Spring @Controller annotation and Java based configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Java configuration and I'd like to build 2 instances of the same controller

```
@Bean(name = CONTROLLER_A)
public MyController getMyAController() {
    return new MyController(new A());
}

@Bean(name = CONTROLLER_B)
public MyController getMyBController() {
    return new MyController(new B());
}

public class MyController {
  ...
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    ...    
  }
}
```

There is no way to annotate the methods as @Controller and without it, Spring doesn't consider that instance as Controller instances (the exception handling doesn't work properly).

Is there a way to get the controller work properly w/o using xml configuration?

EDIT: the only way I can make it works is by extending AbstractController, but I don't really want to use inheritance.

Comment: What do you mean by _Spring doesn't consider that instance as Controller instances_? Also, Spring won't allow you to have duplicate request mappings, so what are you trying to do with two controller beans?

Comment: The exception handling doesn't work. I have a request handler that maps the right instance of the controller based on the URL.

Comment: The problem seems to be elsewhere then. Show us the exception handling you want to see and show us your handler.

Comment: If you would like to have controllers in SpringMVC the ways to do it: extends Controller or use Controller annotation. What you can do: use Controller annotation and for the request mapping use xml to determinate the different behavior.

Comment: @terjekid if I use controller annotations, Spring will create my bean for me. I want to inject different dependencies

Comment: @MaurizioCucchiara The problem that the Controller annotationcreates a bean. In the configuration you are trying to create two beans but not controllers. In SpringMVC only those RequestMappings are registered in the DispatcherServlet which are part of a controller (extends the AbstractController or use the Controller annotation). I think you should check this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/annotation/DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.html and maybe a custom HandlerMapping can register your bean as a controller